# Unable to add expo redirect Uri to the Azure AD B2C applications

Tags: azure, react-native, expo, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement Azure b2c using expo-auth-session. After the login on the browser and redirecting back to the app I get following error.

```
       "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
      "error_description": "AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 'https://auth.expo.io/@username/app-slug' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

Timestamp: 2021-10-13 11:08:53Z
```

When I try to add it under the redirect Uri, I get the error shown in the attached image. [image]

Removing the @ from the username fixes the error but then it will not redirect back to the app.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with this same problem. The validation is a bug in the Azure UI.

You can get around it by grabbing a valid request from the Chrome developer tools, modifying it to insert the `@` symbol (e.g. grab a successful save without the `@` symbol) from the network tab. It will looks something like this:

[image: Picture of dev tools]

Then right click that row for the request that was just made, "Copy" -> "Copy as cURL"

Get that text, paste it in a text editor where you can modify the inputs. You should be able to find the value that was modified in this request, and you can add in your `@` symbol now.

Copy / paste it into your terminal so you can make the request, and, it'll work :) The server does not restrict the `@` symbol from being there.